# Twilio IPM Webhook Validation Failure (validateRequest returns 403)

Tags: twilio

I am unable to verify the signature on Twilio Webhook POST requests

Checklist I've covered:

1. `process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN` is loaded and is clearly received inside the helper `.validateRequest()` function.
2. `X-Twilio-Signature` is present. (i'm using ngrok and confirmed header is present and is received inside the helper `.validateRequest()` function.
3. Tried initially through ngrok, but also now through my public IP VPS.

My Node.js code (shortest complete version):

```
var express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    twilio = require('twilio');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.post('/webhook/ipm', twilio.webhook(), function(request, response) {
    var twiml = new twilio.TwimlResponse();
    twiml.message('This HTTP request came from Twilio!');
    response.send(twiml);
});
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

Twilio Debugger response:

```
{
  "status": 50056,
  "statusText": "Webhook cancelled processing of command",
  "responseTime": "2016-07-13T14:23:38.752Z"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently IPM Web-hooks are in Beta and are not yet signed. So, the issue will persist till they start signing the requests.

--Special thanx to `Phil Nash` Developer Evangalist from Twilio for pointing it out.